# SQL Server full join query - get results only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to show results like below:

```
Date      InvoiceNo  SalesAmount   Date     PaymentType  CheckNo  ReceivedAmount
================================================================================
03-28-2018  C2803       1253.25    Null         Null      Null      Null
03-30-2018  C3001       563.80     Null         Null      Null      Null
04-02-2018  C0205       2311.66    04-02-2018   Check     1253      1816.25
Null        Null        Null       04-05-2018   Check     3565      2311.66
04-06-2018  C0601       560.00     04-06-2018   Check     5231      230.00
04-06-2018  C0602       280.00     Null         Null      Null      Null
04-08-2018  C0805       153.66     04-08-2018   Check     6523      330.00
Null        Null        Null       04-08-2018   Check     6524      280.00
```

The invoice may be issued multiple times a day, and the collection may occur several times a day.

The problem with my query is that when two invoices are generated per day and only one collection is collected, the collection results are duplicated twice.

How to display each result only once?

[image]

Query:

```
select
    S.Date as SDate, S.InvoiceNo, S.SalesAmount, P.Date as PDate, 
    P.PaymentType, P.CheckNo, P.ReceivedAmount
from
    SalesHistory S
full outer join 
    PaidHistory P ON P.Date = S.Date
where
    S.CustCode = '1701' or P.CustCode = '1701'
order by
    isnull(S.Date, P.Date)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow, but I suspect that `union all` is the approach you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ROW_NUMBER and join on it:

```
select
  S.Date as SDate, S.InvoiceNo, S.SalesAmount, P.Date as PDate, P.PaymentType, P.CheckNo, P.ReceivedAmount
from
 ( select *,
      row_number() over (partition by CustCode, Date order by InvoiceNo) as rn
   from SalesHistory
   where CustCode='1701'
 ) S
Full outer Join 
 ( select *,
      row_number() over (partition by CustCode, Date order by CheckNo) as rn
   from PaidHistory
   where CustCode='1701'
 ) P
ON P.CustCode = S.CustCode
and P.Date=S.Date
and s.rn = p.rn
order by
  ISNULL(S.Date,P.Date)
```

I added CustCode to the row_numbers and the join, just in case you want to run this with more than a single customer.